# SQL tuning in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

Is there any article/link available where I can find examples of SQL tuning(Oracle). It would great if it is explain with example. I need something like existing query, statstics, plan and then suggested query/recommendation and new plan.

I found couple of really good links on google:

1. http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_sql_tune.htm
2. http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/

However I m looking for real time examples with above mentioned details, which are missing in these articles.

I hope I m not asking for too much. :-)

Comment: Real-time examples aren't going to be very helpful though as they're so dependant on the data and queries. You need to adapt the examples you can find and look at how to apply the techniques to your situation. Start by getting the plans and timings and look for bottlenecks. You'll find a lot of varied examples here and on asktom.oracle.com, but they can only point you to things to consider for your database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few shortcuts - for best results:

1. Purchase a copy of "Cost-Based
   Oracle Fundamentals" by Jonathan
   Lewis
2. Set up a local Oracle database over
   which you have full control
3. Work through his examples

This book explains how the optimizer makes its decisions.

I'm not sure of the licensing implications for personal use, but also learn how to use the dbms_sqltune package - in cases where it can find an improved plan over the normal optimizer path it will generate a report showing the differences.  You can pick up a lot by looking at this information.

Comment: +1 on the no shortcuts comment, people make careers optimizing oracle applications.

Answer (score 2):

**Writing better SQL:**
Dan Tow's "Tuning SQL" by O'Reilly's a very good cross-platform SQL tuning guide.  It's not a short read, but it does cover some pretty hairy examples and shows you how to tune your queries.  There's no FAST=TRUE option in Oracle; if there were, it'd be hidden and you wouldn't be allowed to change it.  His web site's at http://singingsql.com.

**Tuning by Response Time:**
Cary Millsap's focused heavily on using the Oracle wait interface and queuing theory to tune SQL and systems over the last 20 years or thereabouts; both his current company ( http://method-r.com ) and his previous one ( http://hotsos.com ) have a number of useful resources.

**Tuning via Optimizer Statistics:**
Wolfgang Breitling at http://centrexcc.com has done some excellent work in demonstrating tuning by cardinality feedback to demonstrate that if the SQL's good and there's too much load, the problem can be that you're lying to Oracle (or Oracle's making unsafe deductions) about the nature of the data.  He then shows you how to fix it.

All of these are valuable.  All of these alone are incomplete.

And I second the recommendation of Jonathan Lewis' fine work; he's got a pretty fair tuning blog over at http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using Oracle SQL tuning tool, located here https://sql-tuning.com

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here.  Also, the first sample recommendation is "Instead of COUNT(*) use COUNT(1)", a well-known performance tuning myth for Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/tuning.html

Sql tuning is not easy because it depends on many factors. There is no universal method. Sometimes, just add an index or hint, sometimes need to change the structure.

Comment: Completely agreed.. Thats why I need examples (Best practices) that are tried and tested..!!

Comment: There is no such thing as "best practises" and examples. There are some general rules for OLTP databases. 1) read as little data 2) do not combine large data ranges 3) does not update values in the indexed column 4) do not create indexes on the tiny tables 5) aggregation is bad 6) sort of large ranges of data is bad